# Python 3 Grocery List

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, tuples

Starting with just an empty dictionary, write a **function that creates a grocery list that does the following:**

• Add An Item (takes three inputs from the user: the name of the item, price for one item, and the quantity, then add it to the existing list)

• Remove An Item (takes a string input from the user and removes all instances from the list)

• Print Entire List (prints out all the contents of the list)

• Calculate Cost (prints out the total cost of the items in the list)

• Exit (exit the program)

The items are **taken as three different data types: string (name), float (price), and int (quantity) and all three attributes are stored as one element in the dictionary. Duplicates are NOT allowed.** When an item with the same name is attempted to be added, it will prompt the user to enter a new item again.

When removing an item, it **must not be case sensitive** when matching with the item in the list for it to be removed (in other words “Eggs” and “eggS” still refer to the same item).

**Printing the entire list** this time would now include the price and quantity of the items. The **Calculate Cost** command should **also print the entire list first** before showing the total cost of the items.

The program should continue running until the user decides the terminate it by doing the **Exit** command. Otherwise, it should catch all errors whenever possible.

The output of your code should look like this:
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGjSP.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPPpO.png)

This is what I've come up with but its not like the expected output and some of it are not functioning.

```
grocery_list=()
grocery_history=[]
def grocery_add(): 
    needs_items = True
    while needs_items == True:
        
        print("ITEM ADD \nGive the following information:")
        name=input("Name: ")
        cost=input("Price: ")
        quantity=input("Quantity: ")
        grocery_list={'item_name':name,'quantity':int(quantity),'cost':float(cost)}
        grocery_history.append(grocery_list)
        break


def remove_items(): 
    global grocery_list #since we set grocery list to a new list
    item_to_remove = input("Which item do you want to remove? ").lower() #we set input items to lowercase
    newlist = grocery_list.copy() #set grocery list to newlist
    for item in grocery_list:
        if item.lower() == item_to_remove:
            newlist.remove(item) #remove item and its duplicates
    grocery_list = newlist

def display_list():
    print("\n PRINTING GROCERY LIST...  \n")
    for item in grocery_history:
        print(item)

def calculate_cost():
    grand_total=0
    for item in grocery_history:
        item_total=item['quantity']*item['cost']
        grand_total+=item_total
        print("%d %s @ $%f ea $%f" %(item['quantity'],item['name'],item['cost'], item_total))
        item_total=0

    print("TOTAL COST: ",grand_total)

def redo():
    while True:
        text=str(input("\n What would you like to do? \n 1 - Add an Item \n 2 - Remove an Item \n 3 - Print entire List \n 4 - Calculate Cost \n 5 - Exit program \n  \n Choice: "))
        if text == str("1"):
            grocery_add()
            redo()
        if text == str("2"):
            remove_items()
            redo()
        if text == str ("3"):
            display_list()
            continue
        if text == str ("4"):
            calculate_cost()
            redo()
        if text == str("5"):
            print (" \nThank you for shopping!!!\n \nTerminating Program...")
            quit()
        else:
            print("You should choose among the choices to proceed.")
            redo()

        grocery_add(item)


redo()
remove_items()
grocery_add()
display_list()
```